# Moving some fields from the form to the right

Tags: html, css

So I am building a website and now that I got a register form I might aswell just make it fancy so stuff like address etc comes to the right and personal info stays at the left.

As of now I got

```
<section id="form"><!--form-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="login-form"><!--login form-->
                    <h2>Login to your account</h2>
                    <form method="post">

                   <div id="login-error"></div>

                        <input id="login-mail" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                        <input id="login-pass" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

```
                        <button id="login-     submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div><!--/login form-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <h2 class="or">OR</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="signup-form"><!--sign up form-->
                    <h2>New User Signup!</h2>
                    <form name="signup-form" action="/register" method="post" >
                        <input required id="sign-up-name" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-surname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-mail" type="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-phone" type="tel" placeholder="Telphone"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-gsm" type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Phone"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-pass" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-pass-re" type="password" placeholder="Password again"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-street" type="text" placeholder="Street"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-nr" type="text" placeholder="Nr"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-postalcode" type="text" placeholder="Postalcode"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-city" type="text" placeholder="City"/>
                        <input required id="sign-up-country" type="text" placeholder="Country"/>
                        <button id="sign-up-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button>
                    </form>
                </div><!--/sign up form-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have read something about span but I tried it and it didn't really work. So here it is. Is this something I need to edit in css or in html and what exactly am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide a reference to bootstrap.min.css
I added reference to form control using `class="form-control"` for the inputs
Is this what you are looking for - https://jsfiddle.net/pmankar/qh6sav52/

Try resizing the output pane to see how your final page would be displayed.